# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'version.txt'

Tags: python

I'm having this error when turning a code : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'version.txt'
I don't understand why I have this error because the version.txt file exists in the folder. Can someone help me woth this ?

This is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Purpose: A simple python client that will download all available (completed) scenes for
         a user order(s).

Requires: Standard Python installation. (can also use requests)
"""
import argparse
import base64
import os
import random
import shutil
import sys
import platform
import time
import json
import hashlib
import logging
from getpass import getpass
import urllib.request as ul
import requests

logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.WARNING)

def get_version():
    with open("version.txt") as f:
        return f.read().strip()

version = get_version() 
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
USERAGENT = ('EspaBulkDownloader/{v} ({s}) Python/{p}'
             .format(v=version, s=platform.platform(aliased=True),
                     p=platform.python_version()))

class RequestsHandler(object):

    def __init__(self, host=''):
        self.host = host
        self.creds = None
        self.headers = {}

    def auth(self, username, password):
        basic = ('%s:%s' % (username, password)).encode('ascii')
        self.creds = (username, password)
        self.headers = {
                'User-Agent': USERAGENT + ' (Requests/%s)' % requests.__version__
        }

    def get(self, uri, data=None):
        response = requests.get(self.host+uri, json=data,
                                headers=self.headers, auth=self.creds)
        response.raise_for_status()
        results = response.json()
        return results

    def download(self, uri, target_path, verbose=False):
        fileurl = self.host + uri

        head = requests.head(fileurl)

        file_size = None
        if 'Content-Length' in head.headers:
            file_size = int(head.headers['Content-Length'])

        first_byte, tmp_scene_path = 0, target_path + '.part'
        if os.path.exists(tmp_scene_path):
            first_byte = os.path.getsize(tmp_scene_path)

        self.headers.update({'Range': 'bytes=%d-' % first_byte})
        sock = requests.get(fileurl, headers=self.headers, stream=True)

        f = open(tmp_scene_path, 'ab')
        bytes_in_mb = 1024*1024
        for block in sock.iter_content(chunk_size=bytes_in_mb):
            if block:
                f.write(block)
        f.close()

        if os.path.getsize(tmp_scene_path) >= file_size:
            os.rename(tmp_scene_path, target_path)
        return target_path

class Api(object):
    def __init__(self, username, password, host):
        self.handler = RequestsHandler(host)
        self.handler.auth(username, password)

    def api_request(self, endpoint, data=None):
        """
        Simple method to handle calls to a REST API that uses JSON

        args:
            endpoint - API endpoint URL
            data - Python dictionary to send as JSON to the API

        returns:
            Python dictionary representation of the API response
        """
        resp = self.handler.get(endpoint, data)
        if isinstance(resp, dict):
            messages = resp.pop('messages', dict())
            if messages.get('errors'):
                raise Exception('{}'.format(messages.get('errors')))
            if messages.get('warnings'):
                LOGGER.warning('{}'.format(messages.get('warnings')))
        return resp

    def get_completed_scenes(self, orderid):
        filters = {'status': 'complete'}
        resp = self.api_request('/api/v1/item-status/{0}'.format(orderid),
                                data=filters)
        if orderid not in resp:
            raise Exception('Order ID {} not found'.format(orderid))
        urls = [_.get('product_dload_url') for _ in resp[orderid]]
        return urls

    def retrieve_all_orders(self, email):
        filters = {'status': 'complete'}
        all_orders = self.api_request('/api/v1/list-orders/{0}'.format(email or ''),
                                      data=filters)

        return all_orders

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        pass


class Scene(object):

    def __init__(self, srcurl):
        self.srcurl = srcurl
        self.orderid = self.srcurl.split("/")[4]
        self.filename = self.srcurl.split("/")[-1]
        self.name = self.filename.split('.tar.gz')[0]
        self.cksum_url = self.srcurl.replace('.tar.gz', '.md5')
        self.cksum_file = self.filename.replace('.tar.gz', '.md5')
        self.cksum_name = '%s MD5 checksum' % self.name


class LocalStorage(object):

    def __init__(self, basedir, no_order_directories=False, verbose=False):
        self.basedir = basedir
        self.no_order_directories = no_order_directories
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.handler = RequestsHandler()

    def directory_path(self, scene):
        if self.no_order_directories:
            path = self.basedir
        else:
            path = os.path.join(self.basedir, scene.orderid)
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.makedirs(path)
            LOGGER.debug("Created target_directory: %s " % path)
        return path

    def scene_path(self, scene):
        return os.path.join(self.directory_path(scene), scene.filename)

    def cksum_path(self, scene):
        return os.path.join(self.directory_path(scene), scene.cksum_file)

    def is_stored(self, scene):
        return os.path.exists(self.scene_path(scene))

    def store(self, scene, checksum=False, retry=0):
        if self.is_stored(scene):
            LOGGER.debug('Scene already exists on disk, skipping.')
            return

        for tries in range(0, retry+1):
            LOGGER.debug("Downloading %s, to: %s" % (scene.name, self.directory_path(scene)))
            try:
                self.handler.download(scene.srcurl, self.scene_path(scene), self.verbose)
                if checksum:
                    self.handler.download(scene.cksum_url, self.cksum_path(scene), self.verbose)
                return
            except Exception as exc:
                LOGGER.error('Scene not reachable at %s (%s)', scene.srcurl, exc)
                time.sleep(random.randint(2, 30))


def main(username, email, order, target_directory, password=None, host=None, verbose=False,
         checksum=False, retry=0, no_order_directories=False):
    if not username:
        raise ValueError('Must supply valid username')
    if not password:
        password = getpass('Password: ')
    if not host:
        host = 'https://espa.cr.usgs.gov'

    storage = LocalStorage(target_directory, no_order_directories)

    with Api(username, password, host) as api:
        if order == 'ALL':
            orders = api.retrieve_all_orders(email)
        else:
            orders = [order]

        LOGGER.debug('Retrieving orders: {0}'.format(orders))

        for o in orders:
            scenes = api.get_completed_scenes(o)
            if len(scenes) < 1:
                LOGGER.warning('No scenes in "completed" state for order {}'.format(o))

            for s in range(len(scenes)):
                LOGGER.info('File {0} of {1} for order: {2}'.format(s + 1, len(scenes), o))

                scene = Scene(scenes[s])
                storage.store(scene, checksum, retry)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    epilog = ('ESPA Bulk Download Client Version 3.0.0. [Tested with Python 3.6]\n'
              'Retrieves all completed scenes for the user/order\n'
              'and places them into the target directory.\n'
              'Scenes are organized by order.\n\n'
              'It is safe to cancel and restart the client, as it will\n'
              'only download scenes one time (per directory)\n'
              ' \n'
              '*** Important ***\n'
              'If you intend to automate execution of this script,\n'
              'please take care to ensure only 1 instance runs at a time.\n'
              'Also please do not schedule execution more frequently than\n'
              'once per hour.\n'
              ' \n'
              '------------\n'
              'Examples:\n'
              '------------\n'
              'Linux/Mac: ./download_espa_order.py -e your_email@server.com -o ALL -d /some/directory/with/free/space\n\n'
              'Windows:   C:\python36\python download_espa_order.py -e your_email@server.com -o ALL -d C:\some\directory\with\\free\space'
              '\n ')

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(epilog=epilog, formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)

    parser.add_argument("-e", "--email",
                        required=False,
                        help="email address for the user that submitted the order)")

    parser.add_argument("-o", "--order",
                        required=False, default='ALL',
                        help="which order to download (use ALL for every order)")

    parser.add_argument("-d", "--target_directory",
                        required=True,
                        help="where to store the downloaded scenes")

    parser.add_argument("-u", "--username",
                        required=True,
                        help="EE/ESPA account username")

    parser.add_argument("-p", "--password",
                        required=False,
                        help="EE/ESPA account password")

    parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose",
                        required=False,
                        action='store_true',
                        help="be vocal about process")

    parser.add_argument("-i", "--host",
                        required=False,
                        help="if host is not USGS ESPA")

    parser.add_argument("-c", '--checksum',
                        required=False,
                        action='store_true',
                        help="download additional MD5 checksum files (will warn if binaries do not match)")

    parser.add_argument("-r", '--retry',
                        required=False,
                        type=int,
                        choices=range(1, 11),
                        default=0,
                        help="number of retry attempts for any files which fail to download")

    parser.add_argument('-n', '--no-order-directories',
                        required=False,
                        action='store_true',
                        help='disable generation of order-prefixed directories')


    parsed_args = parser.parse_args()

    log_level = 'DEBUG' if parsed_args.verbose else 'INFO'
    logging.basicConfig(level=log_level, format='%(asctime)s| %(message)s')
    try:
        main(**vars(parsed_args))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        LOGGER.error('User killed process')
    except Exception as exc:
        LOGGER.critical('ERROR: %s' % exc, exc_info=os.getenv('DEBUG', False))
```

And this is all the files contain in my folder : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEm53.png)

Comment: Are you sure you've accounted for differences where the working directory may not be where you say the file is?  Does the process have permissions to it?

Comment: This is a good question. I have to assume that I don't know. How can I know this ?

Comment: As is always in such cases, if you are running it manually, then print out some debug code just before the errant instruction such as saying what the cwd is. If you cannot do that, then open a file in a well known place such as `/tmp/output.txt` & write the debug info to it.

Comment: use the **full path** to the file to be unambiguous.

Comment: Use this code to see the actual current working directory `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: first try with `/full/path/to/version.txt`, later you can use something like `BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` to get folder with code and `full_path = os.path.join(BASE, 'version.txt')` to get full path automatically

Answer (score 1):

Your script can run from different folder so it has different `Current Working Directory` and it searchs file in wrong place

You can check `Current Working Directory` with `print( os.getcwd() )`

First you may try to use `/full/path/to/version.txt`

But more universal method is to use `__file__` to find folder with code and later use it to create full path to `version.txt`

```
import os

BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print(BASE)

full_path = os.path.join(BASE, 'version.txt')
print(full_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use the **full path** of the file to remove any ambiguity.

So something like this:

```py
full_path = ('G:\\My Drive\\darren\\'
             '02_programming\\python\\tests\\'
             'version.txt')


def get_version():
    with open(full_path) as f:
        return f.read().strip()

result = get_version()
print(result)
```

in this example, i explicitly break the past onto multiple lines for clarity.

Comment: It's easier to use forward slashes `/` in file paths.  They work everywhere, even on Windows.

Comment: @JohnGordon,  good point.   i just find it faster to add backslashes because i **copy and paste the windows path** quite often and that is how it comes when it is done that way.